# How can I make a slideshow using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to try using jQuery to make a slideshow, but I'm finding it difficult to get make an array of my classes `slides`. Is there something wrong with the code below?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slideIndex = 0;
    var slides = $('.slides');
    slides[slideIndex].show();

    $('.next').click(function() {
        var i;  
        if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 0;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].hide();
        }

        slideIndex++;
        slides[slideIndex].show();

        var pageNum = slideIndex + 1;
        $('.numbertext').innerHTML(pageNum + "/" + slides.length);
    });

    $('.prev').click(function() {
        var i;

        if (slideIndex < 0) {
            slideIndex = slides.length;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].hide();
        }

        slideIndex--;
        slides[slideIndex].show();
    });
});
```

Comment: please include your html

Comment: One reason there are sooo many jQuery slideshows out there is there are a million ways of creating one. But there is no working slideshow without HTML and CSS.

Comment: There are like 2 zillions of jQuery slideshow plugins out there already. Surely there's need for one more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `slides` array will have DOM nodes, not jQuery objects. So when you want to apply a jQuery method on one individual element, like `hide()` or `show()` you must get the element as a jQuery object. It is better not to take the array element with `[i]` for that purpose, but apply the `eq(i)` method: that will give you a jQuery object for which the `show/hide` methods are available.

For example, change:

```
slides[slideIndex].show();
```

to:

```
slides.eq(slideIndex).show();
```

...etc.

Note that for related reasons it is not necessary to loop over `slides` to hide each element. You can just hide the collection:

Replace:

```
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].hide();
}
```

with:

```
slides.hide();
```

Another issue is your range checking for `slideIndex`. It is placed at the wrong spot, and the `slideIndex > slides.length` should be `slideIndex >= slides.length`

Place those `if` conditions just *after* you do `slideIndex++` or `slideIndex--`.